# Connection of line integral to measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I think whenever we want to integrate some function then there should me measurable space and (i.e measure).My question is how line integral is related to measure? I mean which measure we use on real plane? Is it Lebesgue measure?

Comment: If you wrote down the definition of a line integral the dimension of the measurable space should be come apparent. Whether you do that with Lebesgue or Riemann does not matter much in typical applications of the line integral.

Comment: @KurtG. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral  what they are deriving in this page?i mean which u consider definition ,they are deriving it

Comment: However you want to call that formula . Does this answer your above question ?

Comment: @KurtG. I am confused ,i think they are using lebesgue measure on (R^2) and deriving equivalent form

Comment: A line integral has nothing to do with $2d$-Lebesgue measure. The line has measure zero and so does every integral if you use the $2d$ measure.

Comment: @KurtG. Yeah that's true. (i missed that all line has zero measure).when we do line integral  of some function so domain of function is subset of R?or R^2(confusing as af we consider parametrization domain will be subset of R)

Comment: Perhaps it helps to imagine that the domain of the function is just the *line*.

Comment: @KurtG. My last question: can we integrate function without defining measure on domain?

Answer (score 2):

How to interpret a line integral in terms of measure theory?  We integrate with respect to the "arc length" measure.  In fact, this measure coincides with the $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Similarly, for a surface integral we integrate with respect to the "surface area" measure.  That measure is a constant multiple of $2$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Comment: thank you ! That's what i want . Btw can we intigrate function without defining measure on domain?(i think we cant)

Comment: Can you give hint for how can we define "arc length"  measure?